# TreeView AfterExpand event not firing c#

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, treeview, treenode

I have a TreeView called treeView1, and the following code:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        expanded_tree_node = e.Node;
        MessageBox.Show("the node " + expanded_tree_node.FullPath + " was expanded");
        populateTreeViewNode(expanded_tree_node, expanded_tree_node.FullPath, 0);
    }
```

`expanded_tree_node` is a reference to a `TreeNode`.

The message box never shows when I expand nodes.  Am I missing something?

I'm just learning C# .Net.  Usually I get the skeleton for an event by clicking on a control in Visual Studio.  But in this case, I need to type the event name manually based on the MSDN info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterexpand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Indeed, you need to bind the eventhandler to the event. This would have happened automatically if you had done it like this: In the properties explorer chose the events tab; here doubleclick the one you want to script and both the handler is created and it is added to the event delegate. Now you can simply add your method to the empty field at the AfterExpand entry.

Comment: @TaW, thanks for telling me how to do it using Visual Studio.  Definitely need to have that in my bag of tricks.  I did figure out the answer and am posting it.  Did you downvote me, or someone else?  I wonder why someone would downvote a question like this.  If you had posted this as an answer I could have upvoted and accepted!

Comment: Since my education so far has been using visual, I hadn't realized the connection between the event handlers and where they are defined.  Makes a world of sense now.

Comment: No I didn't downvote you; I usually don't do that, unless something is grossly inappropriate. Somebody probably thought you should have investigated more on your own. Or had a bad day.. Don't let it get you down, it's not important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I could see this failing is if the `TreeView` is not subscribed to the event.

You can subscribe to it via the properties panel at design-time:

[image]

Or place this in your constructor:

```
treeView1.AfterExpand += treeView1_AfterExpand;
```

Comment: Right.  I think that's what was necessary.  Although, following the format of the rest of my automatically generated code, I used `this.treeView1.AfterExpand += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterExpand);` Is that overkill?

Answer (score 0):

In Form1.Design.cs add:

```
this.treeView1.AfterExpand += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterExpand);
```